# Android Emulator Screen off shortcut F7 don't work

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1. Emulator API 19 (4.4.2) works in Windows 7 x64. I want screen off to test my app. To do it I press <kbd>F7</kbd>, but screen is on as before. Also power button (right side of emulator windows) and volume up/down buttons (left side) don't work. How can I turn off the emulator's screen?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that default shortcut for power button has changed from <kbd>F7</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Please note that by default emulator does not have any screen lock set.

Comment: Ctrl + P will close the emulator